# SCP+FIND from remote to local

Tags: ssh, scp

I need to copy some files between a range of dates from a remote server to my pc. I'm having problems when there is more than one file that fits the date condition because in that case my script only manages to copy the first file and outputs the following error for the others:

```
cp: cannot `stat' Â«/path/to/find/filematchingÂ»: No such file or directory
```

My script is:

```
ssh myuser@remoteserver touch --date \'"`date +"%d %b %Y 06:00"`"\' start
ssh myuser@remoteserver touch --date \'"`date +"%d %b %Y %H:%M"`"\' end
scp myuser@remoteserver:`ssh myuser@remoteserver find /path/to/find/ -type f -newer start -not -newer end` /path/to/copy/
ssh myuser@remoteserver rm start
ssh myuser@remoteserver rm end
```

I first thougth that the problem could be that find provides a list of files in a format not manageable by scp but, if I ssh first to the server and then do the scp with the find in the remote machine it works fine (I can't use this option because my script have to be executed automatically), so I guess that ssh is adding some characters I have to scape or something.

Any ideas about what's happening and how to solve it (or any other way to do)? Thank's in advance

Comment: no, you can't do that this with `scp`. It is suitable for simple copy. Rather use `rsync`. It is more appropriate for such complex tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other possible option is to use a for loop:

```
ssh myuser@remoteserver touch --date \'"`date +"%d %b %Y 06:00"`"\' start
ssh myuser@remoteserver touch --date \'"`date +"%d %b %Y %H:%M"`"\' end

for i in `ssh myuser@remoteserver find /path/to/find/ -type f -newer start -not -newer end`;
do 
    scp myuser@remoteserver:$i /path/to/copy/
done

ssh myuser@remoteserver rm start
ssh myuser@remoteserver rm end
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to do a trick:

I wrote the following "myscript.sh"

```
touch --date "`date +"%d %b %Y 06:00"`" start
touch --date "`date +"%d %b %Y %H:%M"`" end
scp `find /path/to/find/ -type f -newer start -not -newer end` myuser@localserver:/path/to/copy/
rm start
rm end
```

Then I run myscript.sh on the remote server:

```
ssh myuser@remoteserver 'bash -s' < myscript.sh
```